# how to send an email with a windows service

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

i am trying to send a mail after a set time but after it reads my redis server it cant send a mail.

```
public class GService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer((e) => GChecker(),null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient("localhost", 5050)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("recon@gmail.com", "BetaButter.12"),
                EnableSsl = false
            };
            await client.SendMailAsync("no-reply@lotusbetaanalytics.com", email, subject, message);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    private void SlaChecker()
    {
        ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("Localhost");
        IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
        var val = db.StringGet("k1");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        {
            string[] Lines = new string[] { val + DateTime.Now.ToString() };
            File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\wisdo\source\repos\GTest.txt", Lines);

        }
    }

}
```

the programs actually runs but it cant send a mail.

Comment: You have no code that calls `SendEmailAsync` in your example.

Comment: how do i call the code for SendMailAsync